# How to get an answer, deleted by a moderator because of "code plagiarized without attribution", undeleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I posted an answer to the question [How to set TextBox.TextDecorations using a ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463147/how-to-set-textbox-textdecorations-using-a-combobox).

There I explained the various problems I encountered and how I overcame it. All of it was original content written by myself. At the end, I wrote:

> Luckily, the WPF source code is now available and I found in the
> TextDecorationCollectionConverter a list of the valid strings, which
> are actually all completely in uppercase, but the converter changes
> the input string to all uppercase too before doing a comparison.
>
> The code of the TextDecorationCollectionConverter is actually rather
> complicated, no wonder I failed writing it myself. Here it is:

I wonder why this is considered "plagiarized without attribution", since I did tell the reader that the code of the TextDecorationCollectionConverter is from the WPF source code.

The sad thing is that this WPF code is **not** the solution, but caused the deletion, I guess. The idea was not that anyone should use this code in their application, since everyone already gets it in the .NET framework anyway. Rather, I meant it as a service to the Stack Overflow reader so that they could check quickly why the strings I used in my solution actually worked.

With hindsight, I understand that providing the GitHub link might help some people to find it.

What I feel sad about is that the answer just got deleted instead of telling me that I could add a link.

How can I get my answer undeleted?

Unfortunately, the person deleting my answer did not indicate which part of the answer he felt was plagiarized. I guessed that it would be the WPF source code, so I posted the same answer again, this time without the WPF source code. Now, I worry, that I'll get scolded here for reposting a deleted answer. But what can I do, when mistakes like this one happen?

Comment: You said the source, but did you appropriately put the code you cited in a quote? Did you provide the original link to the source? (I can't tell, <10k). As for the question: *"How to get Answer marked with "Code plagiarised without attribution." undeleted?"* - cite the source appropriately, correctly format it to show it as a quote, then mod-flag

Comment: If a moderator deletes your post, the proper way to handle that is to fix the problem and mod flag for undeletion. Making a new post instead is asking for trouble.

Comment: The correct action to take here is to cite the source, and quote appropriately, not repost an answer that was mod deleted; that will likely just result in the new answer being deleted too (even if you did attempt to remove any "offending" content). There is (almost) *always* an [edit] feature on your post, so there is never a reason to duplicate it.

Comment: There was a flag on the post that noted your code block appeared to be entirely copied from [this MS reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/TextDecorationCollectionConverter.cs,736fbc7d89c3a020). I would have deleted that myself as it stands

Comment: @Machavity That reads as a really odd complaint to me if the answer outright stated "*The code of the TextDecorationCollectionConverter is actually rather complicated, no wonder I failed writing it myself. Here it is:*". Put another way, they appear to have written "The actual underlying code which I did not write is complicated, here it is for reference". How could that possibly be plagiarism if they noted/ implied the source and didn't claim it as their own? That, _by definition_, can't be plagiarism, even if it was badly formatted. Was the missing link the core issue?

Comment: I think that adding a link to the source would've been better. A Stack Overflow user wouldn't like it if their code were to be copied with only *"I found this on Stack Overflow"*.

Comment: I agree that adding a link might be helpful. I tried to click everywhere, but I could not find originally where I can "mod flag for undeletion". Now I can see an Undelete link. But when I click it, the an error message pops up: "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". Maybe I don't have enough points to ask for undeletion ? Can someone else do it for me ?

Comment: You should raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag (preferably on the post which is of issue) and explain the issue which you want addressed. You are able to do this on your own posts and comments under your posts with any level of reputation. You can do it on any post or comment with > 15 reputation.

Comment: Stack Exchange has [explicit requirements for attribution when using content which you didn't create](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @Makyen: Thanks for the link, but it has only an example for citing text, not code. Of course I don't know the name of the original author. Isn't it enough if I say it is the WPF source code and everyone knows this is from Microsoft ?

Comment: @PeterHuber - You don't know how to quote and cite your sources when writing any professional document?  I find that hard to believe. Why do you believe quoting source code is different then quoting a statement somebody made?  You have been a member for nearly 9 years, you must have seen answers that quoted source code in the past, proper citation and quotation of external sources is vital to the integrity of this community.

Comment: I don't think that source code really adds anything to the answer though, @PeterHuber . If someone wants to consume the original source, then a link to the documentation is more than enough.

Comment: @PeterHuber While additional examples might help, it's unclear to me why you'd think the requirements would be different for code (or *anything* which was copied). Using a `<blockquote>` for larger quotes is preferred (e.g. code formatted code in a quote), but the key requirements are to be *very* clear what's copied, include proper attribution (as the link describes), and not copy more than is really needed. There is *also* the requirement that your post be primarily your own content, rather than primarily content copied from elsewhere (with some possible, but unlikely, edge case exceptions).

Comment: I agree with @zcoop98 that this is not plagiarism, which is defined in the Help center as "posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own". The author clearly stated that the quoted code was not their own. Therefore it should not have been mod-deleted. The only issue is incomplete attribution, i.e., the source is given (WPF source code) but not a link. A comment to the OP would have sufficed to solve this, the OP has 2.5k and is fairly active so they probably would respond. To be safe it could have been deleted with a comment explaining that a link was missing [...]

Comment: [...] and instructions on how to flag for undeletion.

Comment: If the tools help in 99% of the cases, I think it's okay to have some misfires. Not a mod though.

Comment: Code source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/TextDecorationCollectionConverter.cs,736fbc7d89c3a020 -- this isn't a tool backfiring, @IInspectable, there was a mod flag there. It was deleted because it lacked a source link, and I almost did it myself (without any tools). The only reason I didn't was the rest of the text not being plagiarized and I was too tired to figure it out. As an obligatory reminder, linking to the source, assuming it's available online anyway, is a required part of [the referencing guidelines](/help/referencing)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine What if the link becomes invalid in the future and there is no snapshot in the web archive. Do we have to delete the answer in the future then?

Comment: we cross that bridge when we get to it

Comment: @stackprotector You'll note that the requirements for attribution are three-fold: (1) name the original author (if available), (2) link back to the original source, and (3) clearly indicate all copied content using blockquote formatting. If you do #3, then your concern becomes irrelevant. It isn't that snippets of content from elsewhere *cannot* be copied, but that they must be properly attributed and quoted to make clear that they *have been* copied from elsewhere.

Comment: There is a bit bigger issue here when it comes to copying-and-pasting source code with a restrictive license to Stack Overflow. People who contribute to "clean-room" reimplementations of commercial software are generally not allowed to look at the commercial software's source code without getting into huge legal trouble. That means they need to steer clear of Microsoft's "reference source" if they are re-implementing the .NET Framework. Sharing it without a clear indication of its origin is problematic for those users. Not to mention runs afoul of our referencing/attribution guidelines.

Comment: I consider any text, that was not authored by that specific user, to be plagiarism if it's not quoted and cited (this includes linking to the original source).  In every professional and academic setting, that general rule, they also would consider it to be plagiarism. Why would SO have different rules?  Since it's difficult to create a citation list, using the current editor, I would argue that the name of the author is optional (since linking to the original content achieves that goal).

Comment: It is sufficient to just give the name of the author in the text that introduces the quotation; no formal citation format is required. In this case, it's source code, so the "author" is Microsoft. (The onus is not on you, as the person who cites the reference, to go look up who originally wrote the code, e.g., in `git blame`, if that info were even available publicly.) The requirement to provide the author is most critical on Stack Exchange sites, where all content is contributed by a specific author. But it's also nice if you're quoting from someone's blog, GitHub issue, or whatever. @sec

Comment: Just some additional information about me. I am not a professional writer, I have never cited code in my life, I have never seen another question or answer with quoted code. I guess I am quite typical for many who write on SE. Getting an answer just deleted with no obvious way to get it undone is frustrating. Wouldn't it be better to help writers like me, telling me what I should do to improve the answer than just delete it with a cryptic comment ?

Comment: It doesn't scale, @Peter. Stack Overflow gets thousands of flags per day, with only a small number of volunteer moderators to deal with them all. It might be nice in an ideal world to leave personalized comments providing guidance for each and every one, but it just doesn't work. So, we have to just let the Help Center do the heavy lifting. For any legitimate (non-spammer, non-troll) user for whom that information is unclear, they can ask for additional clarification, as you've done. I'm not a professional writer, either, but I learned well in school to cite things I copy from other people.

Comment: @PeterHuber - You have not once after 87 answers and almost 9 years, needed to quote documentation, in order to answer a question? I still don’t understand how quotation of code is significantly different than quoting plain text. When I used the term professional documentation, I meant any writing, that requires proper  citation and quotation of a source. That would include academic papers, professional documentation, answers on this platform, professional journals like IEEE, etc.

Comment: @SecurityHound: I have probably read thousands of answers and I cannot remember any citing source code from somewhere else with links. Maybe I just forgot, but the fact is that there are not many, because most of the answers are just explaining how stuff works  and some example code, which was specifically written to answer the question. SO is not really the place to share lots of code. And until shortly, source code of WPF was not available in WPF, which is my main area of expertise. Also if you think that citing a quote from an author is done in the same as quoting code, you are mistaken.

Comment: @PeterHuber - Quote the code block does not seem difficult or different than quoting text from a website

Comment: @SecurityHound: well, there are actually differences between quoting code and text from an book. For example, SO guidelines require to quote the name of the original author. While citing from a book written by an individual, of course it makes sense to state the author's name. Try to do that when citing WPF source code or any other MS code or OSS code. It's impossible to provide a name. But it might make sense to provide other information if it is code, like which version it is or under which license the code is published.

Comment: I think this discussion (while not providing an actual answer still used as a reference for "Duplicates") was doomed to be fruitless. You can do all you want to make your references and citations bulletproof, and occasionally they may still get deleted. Moderators have earned their reputation by being coding wizards (or by spending excessive time here) and not legal experts - not even in the most basic matters pertaining their field. Yet when you discuss it here, their infallibility unquestioned - in every response , in every comment. That's the reality and you just have to live with it.